# Java Date is one day off from received value

Tags: java, date

I receive response in PostMan containing date as `2013-01-30`

In my Java JSF app, I use **Date** to store this value in my response model class like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="car")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CarResponseModel {
   protected Date receivedDate;
   ...
}
```

However, when the value it gets is one day off like `Tue Jan 29 16:00:00 PST 2013`.

So, January 30th became January 29th for some reason.

I am looking to fix this so my `receivedDate` holds correct date `2013-01-30`.

I am not able to use **LocalDate** due to legacy code and incompatibility with JSF version being used.

Comment: You're seeing the right instant in time for midnight at the start of 2013-01-30 in UTC, 2013-01-30T00:00:00Z, but `Date` is showing you that in your local time zone. Even if you can't use `LocalDate` in that exact spot, I'd suggest you convert the `Date` into an `Instant`, then date a `LocalDate` from that using the UTC time zone

Comment: Is it off by exactly 24 hours, or rather by something like 8 hours, suggesting a timezone issue? Take a close look at the input data and the exact output data, try to test and reproduce it. Can you reproduce it locally, in the same timezone? If yes, debug it!

Comment: @PetrJaneček I dont know, PostMan JSON shows it as "2013-01-30", so no time information, only date portion

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you.  I tried using `receivedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()`  but that was still one day off.

Comment: It is important to take into account client TZ and server TZ (especially when passing values that are locally significant) .. imagine you are US Pacific, but your server is US Eastern. The `Date` for 3pm Pacific is the same value that 6pm Eastern gives ..  What value is important depends on your app ..

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate` is the appropriate type to hold a date-only value. Never use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date` as both were supplanted years by the modern *java.time* types defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @JonSkeet  If you could post your comment as an answer that would be great.  I can then accept it and close this question.  Thanks again for the explanation and suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the right instant in time for midnight at the start of 2013-01-30 in UTC:
2013-01-30T00:00:00Z and 2013-01-29T00:16:00-08:00 represent the same instant in time. Unfortunately, `Date` is showing you that in your local time zone. Even if you can't use `LocalDate` in that exact spot, I'd suggest you convert the `Date` into an `Instant`, then date a `LocalDate` from that using the UTC time zone.